# Opening UDP H.264 video stream on Android

Tags: android, video, h.264, exoplayer

I'm trying to open and display a UDP video stream encoded as H.264 on an Android device. Right now I'm using ExoPlayer somewhat successfully with mp4 files, but it fails on the stream from my Jetson Nano.

Here is Nvidia deepstream pipeline string I'm using to send the stream from my Nano with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 bufapi-version=true ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12, framerate=30/1' ! nvvideoconvert flip-method=2 ! nvv4l2h264enc iframeinterval=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.53 port=4711 sync=0
```

Here is the gstreamer pipeline string I'm able to receive the video stream with on my laptop:

```
udpsrc port=4711 ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Here is the relevant Java code I'm attempting to use to display the stream on my android device:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExoPlayer player;
    PlayerView playerView;
    String udpUri = "udp://0.0.0.0:4711";
    MediaSource mediaSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.PlayerView);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        SetupUdp();
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private void SetupUdp() {
        DataSource.Factory factory = () -> new UdpDataSource(3000, 50000);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(udpUri);
        MediaItem mediaitem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(videoUri).build();
        mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(mediaitem);
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.prepare();
    }
}
```

The apparent output in the app on my android device is just a black screen with a play button that does nothing. Again, I'm able to view other video sources with ExoPlayer just fine. Any help is appreciated.